# materializecss with reactjs (how to import javascript/Jquery in reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

Good day! im trying to work with parallax(materializecss) in reactjs but the pictures does not come out.
i already install the materializecss using npm,

heres my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'materialize-css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import Pic1 from '../img/Pic1.jpg'
import Pic2 from '../img/Pic2.jpg';
import 'materialize-css/js/parallax';

    const About = () => {
    return (
            <div className="paralax">
                <div className="parallax-container">
                    <div className="parallax"><img src={Pic1} alt="Building"/></div>
                </div>
                <div className="class section white">
                    <div className="row container">
                        <h2 className="header">Parallax</h2>
                        <p className="grey-text text-darken-3 ligthen-3">
                        Parallax is an effect where the background content or image in this case, is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="parallax-container">
                    <div className="parallax"><img src={Pic2} alt="Building"/></div>
                </div>
            </div>


        )
    }
    export default About;
```

Comment: Your title is vague, but I assume, you wish to write some code in JSX. That is achieved using `<MyComp>{ /* your code  here */}</MyComp>`

Comment: how to do this in reactjs . https://materializecss.com/parallax-demo.html,

Comment: Also, what are you expecting this: `import Pic1 from '../img/Pic1.jpg'` to do?

Comment: yes, but the picture won't come out.

Comment: how can i use the materilizecss/Js in reactjs.

Comment: I think those imports are causing issues. I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ohkc3aw/). Just try to play with it, give it image links as string. When you import, you get a module, so you cannot give it as `src
`

Comment: it will display if i delete this   <div className="parallax">

Answer (score 0):

Use **react-materialize**.

Install: `npm install react-materialize`

And import Parallax like `import {Parallax} from 'react-materialize';`

Hence your code becomes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Parallax} from 'react-materialize';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Parallax imageSrc="http://materializecss.com/images/parallax1.jpg"/>
      <div className="section white">
        <div className="row container">
          <h2 className="header">Parallax</h2>
          <p className="grey-text text-darken-3 lighten-3">Parallax is an effect where the background content or image in this case, is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Parallax imageSrc="http://materializecss.com/images/parallax2.jpg"/>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have used image hyperlinks. But you can replace them with static images also.

Also, import `jquery` befor `materialise.min.js` in your `index.html`

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

For Reference : https://react-materialize.github.io/#/

**PEACE**

Comment: If you have found my answer helpful and it has solved your query, please accept and upvote the answer. :) @RobbRodirguezJr.

Answer (score 0):

To use Javascript components of Materialize CSS, we need to get the `reference` of that particular element that we're gonna use.

We're using `ref` because we're triggering imperative animations.

**When to Use Refs**

- Triggering imperative animations.
- Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.

As we're using MaterializeCSS which is a third-party CSS framework so in order to use the animations of that we're using `ref`.

[When to use refs in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs)

[CodeSandbox - Parallax Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mm6j730pkj)

You can check other Materialize CSS components in React from this repository - [GermaVinsmoke - Reactize](https://codesandbox.io/s/mm6j730pkj)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import M from "materialize-css";
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
import Image1 from "../public/parallax2.jpg";
import Image2 from "../public/parallax1.jpg";

class Parallax extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    M.Parallax.init(this.Parallax1);
    M.Parallax.init(this.Parallax2);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="parallax-container">
          <div
            ref={Parallax => {
              this.Parallax1 = Parallax;
            }}
            className="parallax"
          >
            <img src={Image2} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="section white">
          <div className="row container">
            <h2 className="header">Parallax</h2>
            <p className="grey-text text-darken-3 lighten-3">
              Parallax is an effect where the background content or image in
              this case, is moved at a different speed than the foreground
              content while scrolling.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          ref={Parallax => {
            this.Parallax2 = Parallax;
          }}
          className="parallax-container"
        >
          <div className="parallax">
            <img src={Image1} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Parallax;
```